# multiple line where clauses

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've got a search page with multiple inputs (text fields).  These inputs may or may not be empty - depending on what the user is searching for.

In order to accommodate this I create a base `searchQuery` object that pulls in all the correct relationships, and then for each non-empty input I modify the query using the `searchQuery.Where` function.

If I place multiple conditions in the WHERE clause I get the following error:

> Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.

```
searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(Function(m) (
                (absoluteMinimumDate < m.ClassDates.OrderBy(Function(d) d.Value).FirstOrDefault.Value) _
                OrElse (Nothing Is m.ClassDates)
                                             )
                                )
```

*I know that code looks funky, but I was trying to format it so you didn't have to scroll horizontally to see it all*

Now, if I remove the ORELSE clause, everything works (but of course I don't get the results I need).

```
searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(Function(m) (
                            (absoluteMinimumDate < m.ClassDates.OrderBy(Function(d) d.Value).FirstOrDefault.Value)
                                                         )
                                            )
```

*This one works fine*

So, what am I doing wrong?  How can I make a multi-condition where clause?

Comment: Not related to your question, but what's up with the [yoda contidion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) `Nothing Is m.ClassDates`? ;)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: That's just one of the conditions I would like to apply.  I found that the error occurs when there is more than one condition, and that happened to be the first condition.  Just trying to simplify the code for posting here.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: Also, I always place my constants on the left side of the comparison.  That way when I'm in a language, like VB, that uses `=` as a dual purpose operator (equality comparator and assignment) a statement like `a = 1` could be confusing and lead to unintended results, whereas `1 = a` leaves no ambiguity and no unexpected results.

Comment: Old JavaScript trick, that is, yes, hrmmm.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: I wouldn't know.  I started doing that 15 years ago in VB6 - well before I wrote any js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple conditions in the `Where` isn't the problem. `m.ClassDates Is Nothing` will never be true and doesn't make sense in SQL terms. You can't translate "is the set of ClassDates associated with this record NULL?" into SQL. What you mean is, are there 0 of them.

If there are no attached `ClassDate` records, `m.ClassDates` will be an empty list. You want `m.ClassDates.Count = 0 OrElse...`

Comment: Ah.  I was thinking in terms of objects and not in terms of SQL.  Thank you.

Comment: It would be syntactically valid in objects, but even there `m.ClassDates` should never be nothing - your entities should have constructors that initialize them to an empty instance of some implementation of `ICollection`.

Comment: Ideally.  Things aren't always ideal.  I was attempting to account for one instance of a non-ideal case that I could foresee.  Meh.  No biggie.  Your advice solved the issue and I'm happy with that.